# How to display data and columns added from a pulgin architecture (loaded assembly) in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, plugins

I have a program that displays data in a DataGridView, and also has a plugin architecture. I wish to have the plugins add additional data columns, and fill those columns, based off of a primary key. For simplicity lets say this key is a string.

I cannot think of, or find a way, to have multiple plugins add multiple columns of data to my program's default set of data, which for now, I have stored in a BindingList. I have tried using Linq to join generic lists, but I have run into the problem that this isn't dynamic enough to handle multiple plugins adding multiple rows.

If I were using SQL, it'd would be as simple as doing many Join statements, but any external database service is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in the C# code behind. Add a column in the DataTable and add a column to the GridView in the code behind, and then databind the datatable to the Gridview again in the code behind. You need uniform datatable that has the extra column and do the same thing in the gridview and bind the two. This needs a little more C# code and make sure the new column data matches with the existing row data, etc.